# dpkg error code #1 telepathy

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, empathy

My empathy is screwed up, and no matter what I do I get this error:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@server:/var/cache/apt/archives#
```

I tried `dpkg -r --force-all empathy` and the error keeps happening
I try to remove `/var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` but it keeps adding itself back.

every other question like this seems to be unanswered.

Comment: You're just removing a cached deb, that's not the installed software, it won't make any difference removing it.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda please advise as what to do about the error.

Comment: So what exactly did you do to trigger the issue?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda not exactly sure

Comment: And when exactly do you get the initial error?

Comment: actually i think it happpened when i installed kubuntu-desktop @ParanoidPanda

Comment: Oh dear, even though the different actual DEs are available in the repositories, it is highly inadvisable to install certain ones together especially ones like GNOME, Unity or KDE because they like to take control of a lot of the system and may not want to hand that control over to another so easily. This is really a way to mess up a system, if you want to use another DE just do a fresh install of that flavour or you'll have to deal with issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the issue was related to this launchpad bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/+bug/1451728

Which was caused by a previous installation of `kubuntu-desktop`

The solution was to run the following as root:

```
dpkg --force-all --purge account-plugin-google
dpkg --force-all --purge unity-scope-gdrive
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```